# Redunt link over single cisco router

Tags: cisco, router, redundancy

I have one cisco router 3825 with multiple WAN card connected to two ISPs
and I have one 2811 with two WAN cards in branch offices.
I need to configure these routers to connect both links and once one is down, the next link will be selected automatically.

I have configured OSPF in both routers and it is running, however when one link is down, it doesn't pick the other link unless the link is physically disconnected.

Comment: It's not very redundant if you've only got a single router.

Comment: It's not OSPF's fault. Mis-configuration's, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If routers [support](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp) SLA, look this [example](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk364/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080211f5c.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

OSPF should easily handle this.
Can you see the OSPF setup configured correctly with sh ip opspf neigh etc.

Also what does your routing table look like when everything is up and running? I'm just asking to make sure you don't have any static routes still in the table as they would take precedence over OSPF installed routes (the AD for static is much lower).